# Twitter reply tweets not always linking to a 'conversation'

Tags: api, rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a Twitter bot that automatically replies to certain tweets. In my Tweet I set the in_reply_to_status_id parameter and I add the username to the text: "@screen_name ..."

The username is taken from status->user->screen_name

When I see my list of replies, only about half of them are linked to a 'conversation' that can be opened. I would like this to be in all cases.

Is this a setting that is turned on or off in user's accounts? Or am I referencing the user in a wrong way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already found the problem: I didn't filter out retweets. Filter them away by adding ' -filter:retweets' to the search query ('q' parameter)